# How to group users together by aws-cognito attributes?

Tags: graphql, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am trying to group users of my application together under a 'Company'.

I have done this in other applications by giving the user's an account attribute/property called "company", which equals a string.

Then all data associated with that company is available to that user.

How can I do this with the AWS Amplify framework?

Answer (score 0):

After some research I was able to figure this out.

In case anyone else runs into this problem...

What I was looking for was what AWS Amplify classifies as a 'Custom Resolver'. Essentially the resolver is the API logic for the GraphQL server on AWS' end.

Within your Amplify project structure there should be a folder called 'Resolvers'.

Mine was in

```
/backend/api/[API_NAME}/resolvers
```

Inside of this folder you are able to place different types of customer resolver logic for your backend.

Ideally you would place two custom files for every custom endpoint.

The two custom files would be as follows:

```
Query.listSomeTable.req.vtl
Query.listSomeTable.res.vtl
```

OR

```
Mutation.createSomeTable.req.vtl
Mutation.createSomeTable.res.vtl
```

These two files will override the resolver logic that AWS produces automatically. The files are in Apache's Velocity Engine format; '.vtl'.

You can read more about it here:
https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/cli-toolchain/graphql#add-a-custom-resolver-that-targets-a-dynamodb-table-from-model

Comment: But this would require to be done for as many mutations or queries that you have in the entire app. How would you optimise that?